# Is is possible to create a batch file or something similar to run CCleaner, MalwareBytes, and Defraggler once a month?

Tags: windows, automatic-maintenance

I am looking for an easy way for my clients to run one simple command that will do these 3 tasks once a month:

- Run Cleaner (CCleaner)
- Scan C Drive (Malwarebytes)
- defrag C Drive (Defraggler)

These are all manual tasks, and I am having trouble getting my clients to do these 3 little things once a month.

Comment: For each of those programs, first look at the documentation and/or help files of each and see if they have any CLI.. This would tell you if it's possible and give you a starting point but using something like `START "title" "app.exe" arg1 arg2 `. You probably should read up and take a stab at trying to create something and post what you are having trouble with if you need the logic to help you automate those tasks.

Comment: Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Unless your clients know exactly what they are doing then running CCleaner can do bad things to the OS.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Windows Task Scheduler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Scheduler).

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446802(v=vs.85).aspx) is the Windows documentation.

You will have to find out how they can be started from the command line to run the tasks you want them to do:

- [CCleaner Command-line
  parameters](https://www.ccleaner.com/docs/ccleaner/advanced-usage/command-line-parameters)
- [Malwarebytes Complete Command Line Switch
  List](https://malwaretips.com/threads/malwarebytes-complete-command-line-switch-list.5528/)
- [Defraggler Command-line
  parameters](https://www.ccleaner.com/docs/defraggler/advanced-usage/command-line-parameters)